# Can RecyclerView with onClickListener in constructor cause memory leak?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks

everyone!

I was searching through the internet but couldn't find an answer to my question. Could such implementation cause a memory leak:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return SomeViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.some_layout), listener)
}
```

Listener passed into the constructor is a simple interface implemented in the activity and passed through constructor into an adapter.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it?  Maybe, depending on what the rest of your code is.

But as long as you're not moving this between `Activity`s, including retaining it across configuration changes in a Fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)`, this, alone, should not cause a memory leak.

Comment: Ok, thx for help. I have no orientation changes in my app and this adapter used in simple fragments which can be opened using navigation drawer